# DOM problems: JS FOR loop is endless and non functional

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is supposed to hide one of the 2 languages when I click the appropiate button, but instead it gets stuck inside an endless loop and doesn't do anything else (that's why I placed the alerts). I did it like this so in case I needed to add more "p" they would change all the same following this loop structure. Also, I don't know if I'm doing it right with the setAttribute part. Should it be as it is, or something like setAttribute("class", "valenciano"+"hide")?

```js
 function valencia() {

        var parra = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for (var i = 0; i < parra.length-1; i+=2) {
            parra[i].setAttribute("class", "valencia show");
            
        };
        for (var j = 1; j < parra.length; j+=2) {
            parra[j].setAttribute("class", "castellano hide");
            
        };
        
}
     
      function castellano(){  
        
        var parra = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < parra.length-1; i+=2) {
            parra[i].setAttribute("class", "valencia hide");
        };
        for (var j = 1; j < parra.length; j+=2) {
            parra[j].setAttribute("class", "castellano show");
            
        };

        }
```

```css
 .hide{display: none;}
 .show{display: block;}
```

```html
 <div><p class="valencia show">Fes-ho amb la cassola, mes fasil no pot ser, preparem l'arros al forn amb tots els ingredients</p>
    <p class="castellano hide">Hazlo en la cazuela, más fácil no puede ser, preparamos el arroz al horno con todos los ingredientes</p>
    <p class="valencia show">aaaaaarròs al forn, que bo que està el nostre arros, xe que bo</p>
    <p class="castellano hide">aaaaarroz al horno, que mal que suena esto en castellano. Oiga que bueno</p></div>
    <input type="button" value="valencià" onclick="valencia();"/>
    <input type="button" value="castellano" onclick="castellano();"/>
```

Comment: In your `for` statements, you aren't actually incrementing the loop variables, just adding to them.  They should be like `i+=2`.

Comment: That's true, but it's just a typo when I pasted and edited it, sorry. It originally was
for (var i = 0; i < parra.length-1; i++) {
            parra[i].setAttribute("class", "valencia hide");
i++
        };

It does the same endless loop anyway.

nevermind, it works here but not when I open up my own file. Consider this solved, thank you.

Comment: It's solved. The code worked (although thanks for the correction in the comments). It was a problem with my own html document that I didn't see till now. Thank you.